# Can't get IDs after reloading jqGrid on specific page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, scroll

I am using jqGrid in MVC application. I am using `"scroll: true"` option. My problem is that; after reloading jqGrid on specific page:

```
$("#jqTable").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: next_page }]);
```

I can't get new IDs which should be there:

```
var ids = $("#jqTable").getDataIDs();
```

---

**EDIT**:

Also, I forgot to say that I even don't see rows of next page after reloadGrid.

Here is more detail explanation:

There is web page where I have to show details of some selected row in jqgrid on Enter key in jquery dialog. I go through grid only with Enter key, one by one row. First Enter = open dialog. Second Enter is Save. So, code where I have to mark current row and select next row, by wish of my customer, is:

```
//declaration of global variables as selected_index -> current index of id in $("#jqTable").getDataIDs() array ...
//...

//In this moment jquery dialog is open. I work on jqgrid on underlying page:

//Set status of current row:
$("#" + selected_row_id).find("td").css("background-color", "azure");
$("#jqTable").jqGrid("setCell", selected_row_id, "Status", "Completed");

//Select next row:
selected_index = selected_index + 1;
temp_id = selected_row_id;
selected_row_id = $("#jqTable").getDataIDs()[selected_index];
if (selected_row_id === undefined) {
    //If I am here it means that I have to jump to next page!
    //Trying to simulate virtual scroll if id is undefined - because id is on the next page!
    current_page = current_page + 1; // SO, IT IS NEXT PAGE!
    $("#jqTable").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: current_page }]);

    //Here selected_row_id is still undefined after this line of code:
    selected_row_id = $("#jqTable").getDataIDs()[selected_index];
}
$("#jqTable").setSelection(selected_row_id, true);
```

Comment: Please provide more code and markup, at least post the chunk of code/event where you get the IDs

Comment: I will. I am new on the site, so I have to wait 8 hours for new post ...

Comment: you should edit your existing question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for tip Maksim!

Comment: Please, help! I don't have solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

$("#jqTable").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(2400);

helps me to scroll programatically, and timeout to wait refresh of grid data helps me to select appropriate row!

But, this is not stable solution. I have to check this ...

Answer (score 0):

`$("#jqTable").trigger("reloadGrid")` and inside of `loadComplete` event handler set selection with respect of `$("#jqTable").setSelection(rowid)`.
try to do like this inside of `loadComplete` event handler,

```
loadComplete: function () {
       selected_row_id = $("#jqTable").getDataIDs()[selected_index];
}
```

---

Assume that you are trying to get ids which are under $("#jqTable") after reload, try this,

```
 var IDs = [];
    $("#jqTable").find("span").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); }); // find with your element as span
```

jQuery's built-in map() function:

```
var IDs = $("#jqTable span[id]")         // find spans with ID attribute
  .map(function() { return this.id; }) // convert to set of IDs
  .get(); // convert to instance of Array (optional)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. With this code I got empty array. But, maybe, my problem is that I am trying to reload grid and get IDs when popup window (jquery dialog) is open, so maybe jqgrid will be reloaded only after dialog is closed. Is it possible?

Comment: Please, help! I don't have solution yet.

Comment: Vedran, Are you trying to get IDs which are under selected row?

Comment: No, I am trying to reloadGrid on next page, and get IDs from this page.

Comment: I see now that if I force page 2 for example: $("#jqTable").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 2 }]); my jqGrid will stil pass page=1 parameter to controller's method. This is why this code does not help.

Comment: Hey, I solved virtual scrolling with:
$("#jqTable").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(2400);
Still, I cannot get ids immediatelly after this line of code. If I could solve this, it will be perfect. Any help?